# Methods and Composition java

Tags: java, methods, composition

I have a facade engine with a method

```
getOwner()
```

I also have another class called Car and another caller Owner. Car class also has a getOwner() method while the Owner class contains the name, the cost of the car and the budget of the owner.

So I have a method to initialize the engine and this calls the constructor in the newCARengine class.

```
public static void iniEngine(String name, int cost) {
    model = new newCARengine(name, cost);
}
```

Composition. The engine class has a car, and the car class has an owner. For me to successfully call the getOwner() method I need to use instance variables (class level variable) to hold a reference to the other object in order to call that method from that object.

MY ENGINE CLASS: [below]

```
public class engine{
    private String name;
    private int cost;
    public Car car;

    public engine(String name, int cost){
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

   public Owner getOwner(){
        return car.getOwner();
    }
}
```

I'm referencing the Car class by using an instance variable for that class "public Car car;" which then allows me to use "car.getOwner();" method.

MY CAR CLASS: [below]

```
public class Car{
    public Owner owner //instance variable to reference the owner class
    public Owner getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Now i'm ready to go to the Owner class where the Owner object is created.

MY OWNER CLASS: [below]

```
public class Owner{
    private String name;
    private int cost;
    private int budget;

    public Owner (String name, int cost){
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    public Owner (String name, int cost, int budget){
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.budget = budget;
    }
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public int getCost(){return cost;}
    public int getBudget(){return budget;}
}
```

Now I am doing something wrong as when I run the iniEngine() method, I get a nullpointer exception and this I belive is a result of the object not being created. The error is generated from here:

```
return car.getOwner();  //from the ENGINE CLASS
```

I need to return an object as a result of my engine class. but the object is not getting created. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: To my way of thinking, the engine's "owner" is the car itself, not the car's owner.

Comment: where are you setting the field `car` from your `engine` instance?

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code several times. I don't understand where you associate an owner to a car. 
This is what causes the NullPointerException 
I suggest you provide a CTOR to Car that gets Owner as parameter and in addition, consider having a setCar method. 
Consider using the following code for Car:

```
public class Car{
    public class Car(Owner owner) {
      this.owner = owner;
    }
    private Owner owner //instance variable to reference the owner class

    public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
       this.owner = owner;
    }
    public Owner getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Style note: in Engine, car should probably also be `private`, just like the other fields, with either a setter, or a constructor argument.

It seems like some of the fields are not getting set.  One debugging "trick" I use in similar cases is to temporarily make the fields `final`, and see what the compiler complains about.  For example, if anybody is setting `engine.car`, it would complain.  In this case, that is a good thing - it should be complaining!  And, if *nobody* is setting `engine.car`, that's a red flag as to where the NPE is coming from.

Alternatively, if you do have setters/getters, put breakpoints in them (or, if you prefer, add System.out.prints)  to verify that they are getting called.  Or, temporarily rename them (I add "xxx" to the beginning) to verify that the compiler complains, proving that somebody is calling them.

Answer (score 0):

I never instantiated the objects and only delcared the variables.

By changing the constructor to

```
public Engine(String name, int cost) {
    car = new Car(new Owner(name, cost));       
}
```

This created the objects successfully which in turn allowed me to call the getOwner() method and not get any NullPointerExceptions. Must have missed this part somehow.